# ListView not showing image from URL on initial list load but only when items are scrolled of and on the screen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

In custom widget HorizontalListView I'm displaying image from URL.

Problem is that for each item in the this ListView image is loaded from URL only when item appears on screen for the second time, which probably means after view is recycled. Why URL image is not loaded when view item is shown for the first time I don't know. At first thought maybe it is custom view problem but I tried with regular ListView ending up with same issue.

For loading image I'm using ImageLoader I found on web. I'm stuck with this for about 7-8h now and any help would be appreciated

Here is adapter:

```
public class ItemPreviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

    private final List<HashMap<String, String>> items;
    private final LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    ImageLoader imgLoader;


    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView item_name;
        TextView item_price;
        ImageView image;
    }

    public ItemPreviewAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        imgLoader = new ImageLoader(context);
        this.items = map;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.lvitem_homepage_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.item_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemName);
            holder.item_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvItemPrice);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivItemImage);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();


        HashMap<String, String> item = items.get(position);

        String id = item.get("id");
        String item_name = item.get("iname").toUpperCase();
        String item_price = item.get("new_price").toUpperCase();
        String currency = item.get("currency").toUpperCase();


        holder.item_name.setText(item_name);
        holder.item_price.setText(item_price+" "+currency);

        String image_url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/images/items/cropped_image_list_id_"+ id + ".png";
        imgLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, holder.image);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

ImageLoader:

```
public class ImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.ic_launcher;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);


        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            // imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }


    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 1;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
            if(tag != null && ((String)tag).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}
```

Task:

```
private class LatestItems extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... loc_id) {

        // For storing data from web service
        String data = "";

        // Downloader object
        UrlDownloader downloader = new UrlDownloader();

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/web_services/home_screen_latest_items.php?loc_id="
                + loc_id[0];

        try {
            // Fetching the data from web service in background
            data = downloader.downloadUrl(url);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Downloader exception", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String downloadedData) {
        super.onPostExecute(downloadedData);

        //If web service returned data
        if (downloadedData != null) {
            JSONObject jObject;

            // Instantiate parser
            ItemJSONParser itemsParser = new ItemJSONParser();

            try {
                // Put data into JSON Object and pass it to parser
                jObject = new JSONObject(downloadedData);
                items = itemsParser.parse(jObject);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiate adapter. Provide Context, Item layout and
            // DataSource (result)
            ItemPreviewAdapter itemPreview = new ItemPreviewAdapter(
                    getApplicationContext(), R.layout.lvitem_homepage_item,
                    items);

            // Pass each data to from list into to adapter
            for (HashMap<String, String> data : items) {
                itemPreview.add(data);
            }

            // Set adapter
            latestItemsList.setAdapter(itemPreview);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Its great that you wrote your own implementation of an imageloader with asynctask but it might be easiers to just use an image loading library like [Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) or [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). With volley you would have to implement som stuff yourself. With Picasso you can replace the ImageLoader class with just 1 line of code which does image loading and caching to disk/memory and image placeholder and error images `Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);`

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `itemPreview.notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting the adapter, in the onPostExecute() of the asynctask.

Answer (score 0):

Here you did not bind your list to parent :

Replace

```
public ItemPreviewAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        ....
        }
```

with

```
 public ItemPreviewAdapter(final Context context, final int textViewResourceId, List<HashMap<String, String>> map) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId,map);
        ....
        }
```

and one more thing

```
if (convertView == null) {
             .....
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}
```

Add else when get holdertag..

Thats it...